# Set Batch Size for JEST Bulk Request

Tags: java, elasticsearch, bulkinsert, elasticsearch-jest

How to set Batch Size for JEST Bulk Requests JAVA API?

Currently the Bulk Request does not work on Batch Size greater than 10 in my case, is there some way to increase this limit?

Comment: use bulkprocessor .? I think this should help https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-bulk-processor.html

Comment: Does JEST client support it?